# Where does makensis place the nsis outfile?

Tags: nsis

Where does `makensis` place the `OutFile`? Is it in the directory where the `.nsi` file is or is it the working directory where `makensis` was called?

For example:

command-line:

```
makensis .\dir\to\script.nsi
```

script.nsi:

```
OutFile setup.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

From testing your script.nsi, it places it relative to the script.nsi file:

```
Processing config: ...\NSIS\nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "...\dir\to\script.nsi" (ACP)

Processed 1 file, writing output (x86-unicode):

Output: "...\dir\to\setup.exe"

...

1 warning:
  9000: Insecure filename "setup.exe", Windows will unsafely load compatibility shims into the process.
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is relative to the current directory. The current directory is set to the directory of the .nsi file unless you run MakeNSIS with the `/NOCD` switch. The current directory can be changed by the script with `!cd`.

```
OutFile Test.exe ; Written to same directory as  the .nsi
```

or

```
!cd "c:\something"
OutFile Test.exe ; Written to c:\something\Test.exe
```